mTLS trust anchors deprecated in Keycloak?
We are using KC_HTTPS_TRUST_STORE_FILEto list the CA certificates for which KeyCloak should accept client certificates in mutual TLS. These are private CAs that are not in the trust store of the OS (or the JRE, but that's hopefully the same thing). But now we are getting a warning that it's deprecated and we should use the "System Trust Store" which is something that Keycloak constructs from the OS/JRE trust store and files in KC_TRUSTSTORE_PATHS. But we don't want to send all the CA certs in the world in the TLS handshake, and we don't want to accept GlobalSign or Let'sEncrypt EE certificates as client auth, and we don't want to trust servers that somehow have an EE cert from one of our private CAs.
What gives? What should we do once KC_HTTPS_TRUST_STORE_FILE disappears?
(The name of the configuration setting is a bit confusing, or even misleading. It would be natural to assume that it does indeed point at a file containing trust anchors for outgoing TLS, in which case the deprecation would make sense. But it is in fact the one used for mTLS; I have tested it with openssl s_client and see the certificates in the file as "Acceptable client certificate CA names").

‘Trust anchors for outgoing TLS’ doesn’t make sense. Truststores are for incoming certificates.

@user207421, well, yeah, if Keycloak initiates a TLS connection to another server, the other server's EE certificate is 'incoming' in the Server Hello part of the handshake. But I still think of it as a outgoing TLS when Keycloak has the role of client in TLS.
The point is that Keycloak receives EE certificates from clients using mTLS, and from the Server Hellos of other servers when it connects to them, so it needs two different trust stores.

And just as expected, if I don't set KC_HTTPS_TRUST_STORE_FILE, I get a list of all the CAs in the System Trust Store as acceptable CAs for mTLS. Which adds 14728 bytes to the handshake. And the backend only accepts EE certificates issued by one state-run CA (non-public) so that's basically wasted bandwidth.
